# Django project sending back Category Object instead of name of that Category

Tags: python, html, django

So at the moment when I go to get the view page of my html page Measurements the Category column should show the name of the category West, East, or Volcanoes. However at the moment it is just showing Category object. If there is more then one category object then it will display it as category object, category object instead of West,East

Here are my models:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=100) 

class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Area')
```

And here is my function to get that data.

```
@property
    def category_names(self):
         result = Category.objects.filter(members__id=self.id)
         return ", ".join(str(res) for res in result)
```

What am I doing wrong? The def category_names is under my Area models so the self.id is from area. I'm sure it has something to do with my function. Always when it comes to django I'm just missing something small but not sure what....

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `__unicode__` method to your Category class:

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Area')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

or return the name of the category when you build the list:

```
return ", ".join(str(res.name) for res in result)
```

Comment: Yup damn it was .name was what I was missing :( Ha I miss c# :( Thanks so much!!

Comment: Man :( I spent hours trying to figure that out uhhh cant believe i missed that so simple :(

Comment: yeah, sometimes that happens ;-) That is why I use to add `_unicode_` method to the classes could be shown somehow.